Need clarification on string acceptance definition for deterministic PDAs
I am currently reading the determinstic pushdown automaton from "Introduction to Theory of Computation", 3e by M. Sipser. I wanted to seek more clarification on DPDA's accepting a string. The question is - does the below DPDA accept the empty string?
I have also attached an image showing the formal description of DPDA as per Sipser and the quoted definition of acceptance for a DPDA.


Acceptance Definition - Introduction to Theory of Computation (3e), page - 131

Acceptance for DPDAs works in the same way it does for PDAs. If a DPDA enters an accept state after it has read the last input symbol of an input string, it accepts that string. In all other cases, it rejects that string. Rejection occurs if the DPDA reads the entire input but doesn’t enter an accept state when it is at the end, or if the DPDA fails to read the entire input string. The latter case may arise if the DPDA tries to pop an empty stack or if the DPDA makes an endless sequence of ε-input moves without reading the input past a certain point.

Seeking Clarification
For the empty string, can the DPDA go to state $q_1$, thereby accepting it, or will the computation end at $q_0$, and the string considered as rejected?
Thank you.

UPDATE-1
I am also adding the definition of a PDA and its acceptance.

The definition of acceptance is taken from page-114

According to this definition, if we consider the above deterministic PDA to be a non-deterministic PDA, then it accepts the empty string. The author says that the definition of acceptance for D-PDA and N-PDA is same, but in the same paragraph the author also says

Rejection occurs if the DPDA reads the entire input but doesn’t enter an accept state when it is at the end,...

From this, I infer the following - "as soon as the DPDA reaches end of input, if it is not in a final state, reject the string." So from this perspective, the empty string should not be accepted. This is because at the very beginning of the computation, the DPDA has no input to process and its current state is $q_0$, which is a non-final state. So the D-PDA, according to its definition, must reject the empty string. Had the state $q_0$ been an final state, the D-PDA would have accepted the empty string. But that is not the case.
I think this is where my confusion is rooted in. The same automaton accepts the empty string when viewed as an N-PDA, but rejects the empty string when viewed as a D-PDA. Am I making any mistake in my understanding?

“Acceptance for DPDAs works in the same way it does for PDAs.” What is the book's definition of PDA acceptance?

@JeanAbouSamra Added the definition of NPDA acceptance and further elaborated on my confusion. Hope that helps.

What do you think? What did you try? You need to show us where you are stuck so that we can help you understand.
